# Delete autocomplete url suggestions from macbooks

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Normally the shortcut is shift+delete, fn-delete or another combination that includes delete. But new macs dont have a delete key.

Comment: Do you mean an individual URL or all URL's?

Comment: an individual url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a star beside the URL those are bookmarked, so you won't be able to delete those. If you want to delete those suggestions, you will have to edit/modify your chrome bookmarks.

If they aren't highlighted, you could try pressing

```
FN+SHIFT+DELETE
```

3 times

the delete button could be referred to as the backspace one